# replicate a SQL report in powerbi - create 2 queries and merge them to get result

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns, powerbi-desktop, measure, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to create a report in power BI where I have to create one query which creates 30 calculated columns, then merge it with another query with left outer join to get my results. I am using measures to do my calculations to create the 30 columns and when I bring them together in report view, I lose my results from the second query.

I tried to create calculated columns in a new table to store results but since all calculations do a distinct count of account numbers, I am unable to put results in the same table, so I used measures to do my calculations.

Cannot post the code online :(

Expected result:

```
School name Code Col1 Col2 Col2
a           ABC  1000    0    0
b           BBB  2000 2000 2000
c           AAB     0    0    0
d           NNN  4000 4000    0
e           ACE     0    0    0
```

Getting this result

```
School name Code Col1 Col2 Col2
a           ABC  1000    0    0
b           BBB  2000 2000 2000
d           NNN  4000 4000    0
```

Comment: What kind of help do you expect without code? Some rows are missing from your output, find out why.

Comment: Please give us the source data of the two tables so we can help you..